# Is Apple Mail stationery compatible with Microsoft Outlook (Mac and Windows)?

Tags: macos, mac, email, microsoft-outlook, apple-mail

Is Apple Mail stationery compatible with Microsoft Outlook (Mac and Windows)? I don't have access to any version of Microsoft Outlook to test it, and I wasn't able to find anything on web regarding the possibility to use/import a mail stationery from Apple Mail to MS Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's Mail stationery is **not compatible** with Microsoft Outlook, nor there is an automated way to import a stationery. Though MS Outlook has stationery, these are very basic (just some backgrounds, to enhance the message). I guess Microsoft didn't insisted on the idea of stationery because it's very easy in Outlook to format an email (the formatting tools are very powerful, compared to the spartan options of Apple's Mail).